# How to Remove MS Teams Meeting from Outlook Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-teams

How do I prevent a Meeting scheduled in MS Teams from showing up on the calendar in Outlook?

I have multiple Teams meetings that repeat every day and they are being echoed in the Outlook calendar. They do not represent something that needs a reminder, and I do not need to worry about conflicts with other meetings. Their presence in Outlook is accomplishing nothing except cluttering up the calendar in Outlook and making it impossible to see other more important, non-repeating items.

Is there a way to kill this "feature".

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: You could set those meetings in Outlook to category Yellow (or whatever you prefer) and then customize the view (View --> Current View --> View settings) by setting an advanced filter which filters out all Yellow items (Filter --> advanced --> Field --> Categories "does not contain" "yellow" --> Add).

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, MS Teams calendar items will be synced to your Outlook calendar and if you remove MS Teams Meeting from Outlook Calendar, it will also disappear from your  MS Teams calendar. This feature is integrated and seems there is no options for us to change this.
Compared with killing this "feature", I would suggest you to cancel those unnecessary recurrence meeting items to avoid conflicts.

Comment: They are not unnecessary, they are trivial. They exist to allow anyone on the team to launch the meeting, rather than waiting for the owner of the channel to start things. To my knowledge, there is no other way to set up a meeting that allows anyone on the team to start it.

Comment: Okay, sorry for have not found more related workarounds yet. Maybe I can understand those trivial calendar items were used to reminder users in organization to launch a meeting? If so , what if creating recurrence email reminders to replace those trivial calendar items?

Comment: While an interesting idea, that still doesn't solve the problem of "anyone being able to start the meeting". Plus, these are students. They don't check their email regularly, and most of them have notifications turned off.

Comment: If necessary, maybe you could post a suggestion in Microsoft User voice, then other users will could vote on it for you, Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version.